# How does the "click_link" method of Capybara know which link to click, when the page has several identical links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara, railstutorial.org

This comes from the Rails Tutorial:

```
     expect { click_link('delete') }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
```

If the page being tested has several links called "delete", but each has a different URI (based on an id), how then does Capybara know which link to click?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It checks the id, value and text of a given element. If you have non-unique links, you may need to scope the click command

```
within(#some_id_div) do
  click_button "my button"
end
```

Also, for that particular test, it's not going to matter because all the links refer to deleting a user

Comment: should be 
within('#some_id_div') do
  click_button "my button"
end